# Is undefined behavior changing a literal array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, undefined-behavior

I have the following situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A {
    double* a;
};
struct A data = {
    (double[]) {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}
};
void f() {
    data.a[2] = 2.2;
    printf("%f\n", data.a[2]); // situation 1
}

int main() {
    f();
    printf("%f\n", data.a[2]); // situation 2
}
```

I'd like to know if the two labeled situations are undefined behaviors or not. I believe that situation 1 is not a undefined behavior (once I use `data` only inside `f`), but situation 2 actually is.

In the case of not being undefined behavior, if I change `data.a[2] = 2.2;` inside `f` to `data.a = (double[]) {2.1, 2.2, 2.3};`, I would get undefined behavior?

Comment: No UB here as far as I can tell. Non-string literals are mutable.

Comment: Why do you think situation 2 is undefined behavior?

Comment: Aside: *warning C4716: 'f': must return a value*. Is there anything your actual code is doing which uses the function value?

Comment: @WeatherVane, chaging to `void`... sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to know if the two labeled situations are undefined behaviors
>   or not. I believe that situation 1 is not a undefined behavior (once I
>   use data only inside f),

C specifies the behavior of all the operators involved, and it has no restrictions on their use with the objects or sequence of events appearing in the example code.  So the behavior is defined.

> but situation 2 actually is.

C specifies the behavior of all the operators involved, and it has no restrictions on their use with the objects or sequence of events appearing in the example code.  So the behavior is defined.

The object `data` is declared at file scope, so its lifetime spans the entire run of the program.  Its one member is initialized with a pointer to the first element of an array expressed as a compound literal, and since that compound literal appears outside the body of any function, its lifetime, too, spans the entire run of the program.  Furthermore, its type (in this case) is `double[3]`, which is not `const`-qualified, so its elements may be assigned to.

> In the case of not being undefined behavior, if I change data.a[2] =
>   2.2; inside f to data.a = (double[]) {2.1, 2.2, 2.3};, I would get undefined behavior?

Yes, in `main()`.  A compound literal appearing *inside* a function body has automatic duration, so its lifetime ends no later than when the function returns.  At that point, any pointers to or into it become indeterminate, and any attempt to dereference them (as `main` thereafter does) has undefined behavior.

Comment: Being a little bit off topic, when I use `data.a = (double[]) {2.1, 2.2, 2.3};`, the compiler makes a copy of the numbers where the literals are stored or `data.a` points to the program memory region where the literals are?

Comment: Compound literal is an unnamed object. You simply point `data.a` to it.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo, it is analogous to `double b[] = {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}; data.a = b;`.  In the compound literal case, there just isn't any identifier by which you can later refer directly to the array.  Much the same applies when you use the compound literal in an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is perfectly fine array compound literals are mutable.

---

> In the case of not being undefined behavior, if I change data.a[2] =
>   2.2; inside f to data.a = (double[]) {2.1, 2.2, 2.3};, I would get undefined behavior?

If you meant this,

```
void f() {
    data.a = (double[]) {2.1, 2.2, 2.3};
    printf("%f\n", data.a[2]); // situation 1
}
```

Yes it is undefined behavior, since compound literals are local to scope. Thus you cannot use them as reference and it will be vanished once control exits the function.